# Can a Canadian citizen claim tax-exemption on a U.S. scholarship intended for travel costs?

Tags: united-states, canada, tax-exemption, scholarship

I am a Canadian citizen, and have received a scholarship of $750 from a U.S. institution to pay for lodging and travel costs. I am required to fill out a W-8BEN form, and I was wondering if I can claim tax-exemption for the scholarship? And if so, how?

(I am a student in a degree program, and do not currently have an SSN or ITIN.)

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page on the IRS site](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/withholding-federal-income-tax-on-scholarships-fellowships-and-grants-paid-to-aliens), assuming that you are residing in the US during your time at college, and this appears to be the case by the nature of your scholarship, then no, the scholarship income is not reportable to the IRS.